# app closes when directed to second acivity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hi I am new to Android stuff.Right now I'm following the tutorial  given in  developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html  and building my fist app.It was fine until I dealt with single activity.Later I have added second activity.When I click the button in first it  should be directed to second activity.But on clicking first activity my app stops suddenly.Please help me.
here's the logcat

> 06-23 23:10:50.134: E/FragmentManager(437): No view found for id
>   0x7f05003c (com.example.honey:id/container) for fragment
>   PlaceholderFragment{43e98050 #0 id=0x7f05003c} 06-23 23:10:50.134:
>   E/FragmentManager(437): Activity state: 06-23 23:10:50.264:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-23 23:10:50.264:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(437): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.honey/com.example.honey.DisplayMessageActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c
>   (com.example.honey:id/container) for fragment
>   PlaceholderFragment{43e98050 #0 id=0x7f05003c} 06-23 23:10:50.264:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(437):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   06-23 23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   06-23 23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 06-23
>   23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   06-23 23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-23
>   23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 06-23 23:10:50.264:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(437):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 06-23
>   23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-23
>   23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 06-23 23:10:50.264:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(437):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   06-23 23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 06-23
>   23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-23 23:10:50.264:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(437): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.honey:id/container) for
>   fragment PlaceholderFragment{43e98050 #0 id=0x7f05003c} 06-23
>   23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
>   06-23 23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
>   06-23 23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):    at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>   06-23 23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
>   06-23 23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
>   06-23 23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
>   06-23 23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3781) 06-23
>   23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2636)
>   06-23 23:10:50.264: E/AndroidRuntime(437):    ... 11 more

1st activity java file

> ```
> package com.example.honey;
>
> import android.content.Intent; 
> import android.os.Bundle; 
> import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; 
> import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
> import android.view.Menu; 
> import android.view.MenuItem; 
> import android.view.View; 
> import android.view.ViewGroup; 
> import android.widget.EditText;
>
> public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {     
>     static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.honey.MESSAGE";
>
>     public void sendMessage(View view){     Intent intent=new
>         Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);     EditText
>         editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_query);     String message =
>         editText.getText().toString();     intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,
>         message);     startActivity(intent);     
>     }
>
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>         if (savedInstanceState == null) {
>             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new
> ```
>
> PlaceholderFragment())
>                  .commit();
>               }
>           }
>
> ```
>     @Override
>     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>
>         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>         // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
>         // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
>         // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
>         int id = item.getItemId();
>         if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
>         return true;
>         }
>         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
>      */
>     public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
>
>         public PlaceholderFragment() {
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>             View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
>             return rootView;
>         }
>     }
>
> }
>  }
> ```

1st activity fragment_main.xml

> 

For 2nd activity

```
package com.example.honey;

import android.content.Intent; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem; 
import android.view.View; import
android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override     
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         Intent intent=getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);         
        String message=intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);         
        TextView textView =new TextView(this);         
        textView.setText(message);
        setContentView(textView);



        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();         
        }
    }

    @Override     
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.         
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
        return true;     
    }

    @Override     
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {         
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will         
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long         
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.         
        int id = item.getItemId();         
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {             
            return true;
        }         
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);     
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.      
     */     
     public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {         
        }

        @Override         
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,container, false);
            return rootView;         
        }
    }
}
```

XML file

> ```
> android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
> android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
> android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
> android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
> tools:context="com.example.honey.DisplayMessageActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
> ```
>
> > 
>
> ```
> <TextView
>
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
> ></TextView> </LinearLayout>
> ```

manifest

> ```
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="8"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
>
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
>     <activity
>         android:name="com.example.honey.MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity
>         android:name="com.example.honey.DisplayMessageActivity"
>         android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
>         android:parentActivityName="com.example.first.MainActivity" >
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
>             android:value="com.example.first.MainActivity" />
>     </activity>
> </application>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a silly error in the second activity code due to copy pasting:

DisplayMessageActivity:

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();         
    }
}
```

You're trying to add the PlaceholderFragment to the R.id.container, when the content view of the second activity is the TextView, which does NOT have the container, aka the layout specified by R.id.container does not exist in the second activity.

Remove these lines from the second activity and it should work.

Comment: Thanx a lot , may I know when should I the above code and when I shouldn't?Actually what does the above piece of code specify?

Comment: The above code is called dynamically adding a Fragment to a specific layout (usually an empty FrameLayout, specified only to be a "container" for the Fragment itself). Therefore, it's meant to be used if you want to add the PlaceholderFragment to a layout, basically. And you shouldn't if that's not what you want to do, although I like my views all being in Fragments, and not in the Activity (because orientation change is easier to handle). More info: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the activity to the manifest I think...

```
    <activity
        android:name="DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/..." >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your XML layout for MainActivity, you specify findViewById(R.id.edit_query) for your EditText which was never declared.

Add the stared line to your fragment_main.xml file

```
`<EditText
   **android:id="@+id/edit_query**
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="@string/edit_message"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>`
```

Comment: I have added  ,still app stops

Comment: Post the error log you got after adding the line. Your layout view doesn't indicate where your button is and how you handle the click event.

Comment: Done new catalog posted

Comment: I'd like to see your button definition, does it have attribute android:onClick="sendMessage"?

Comment: yes,you can check it in fragment_main.xml posted above

Comment: Your fragment_main.xml only has one EditText that I can see

Comment: <Button 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/button_send"
       android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

Comment: Don't why  isn't showing even after repostong.I've commented my button attributes